# What does "online polarization" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

[Cinelli, 2021](https://www.pnas.org/content/118/9/e2023301118) says

> Online polarization, for instance, may foster misinformation spreading.

I did a search about the use of "[polarization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization)"

> segregation of society into social groups, from high-income to
> low-income

But I still do not fully get what does "online polarization" mean, and how to understand the sentence of Cinelli, 2021 above.

Comment: [polarization](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/polarization) - 'the act of dividing something, especially something that contains different people or opinions, into two completely opposing groups:
_The polarization of society into rich and poor can clearly be seen in urban areas_.'.

Comment: You've picked one particular usage of **polarization** from that Wikipedia page. The word is used more broadly, to mean "_Division into two sharply contrasting groups or sets of opinions or beliefs._" Wealth isn't necessarily what polarizes the online communities.

Comment: Think of the globe (Earth). There are two poles, Polarization means everything becomes an issue of one extreme or the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cinelli might be pointing out how algorithms may guide users into more extreme social or political positions. You click on a thing you like, the machine suggests things that are even MORE that.

To use a hopefully non-polarizing example, think of how your ads change when you are shopping. You buy one toilet seat and are shown ads for a dozen new ones. This happens with other content you view, too. You look up an article or watch a video and you are guided to more content like that, and so on, and so on.

I think Cinelli is saying that, when you are looking at political content and enter this funnel, it pushes people away from a perceived middle and into pole-like positions.

Additionally, in this process, you are guided away from positions, people, or opinions that might contradict you, which means misinformation does not have many opportunities to be challenged or corrected.